# Problems with creating XML with DOMDocument in PHP

Tags: php, xml, dom

The below code is fetched from php.net (http://docs.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savexml.php). My problem is - it doesn't work. My only output from this is: "Saving all the document:  Saving only the title part:". What am I missing here?

```
$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0');
  // we want a nice output  
  $doc->formatOutput = true;   
  $root = $doc->createElement('book');
  $root = $doc->appendChild($root);  
  $title = $doc->createElement('title');  
  $title = $root->appendChild($title);
  $text = $doc->createTextNode('This is the title');  
  $text = $title->appendChild($text); 
  echo "Saving all the document:\n";  
  echo $doc->saveXML() . "\n";
  echo "Saving only the title part:\n";  
  echo $doc->saveXML($title);
```

Comment: Do you want to send an xml document to the client? Or do you want to send an html document that includes that "shows" the source code for one or more xml documents/fragments?

Answer (score 0):

PHP sends a [Content-type http header](http://de.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.default-mimetype). And by default it's `text/html`. I.e. the client is supposed to interpret the response document as html. But you're sending an xml document (and some text and another fragment, which invalidates the output).
If you want to send an xml document tell the client so, e.g. via `header('Content-type: text/xml')`

```
$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0');
$doc->formatOutput = true;

$root = $doc->appendChild($doc->createElement('book'));
$title = $root->appendChild($doc->createElement('title', 'This is the title'));

if (headers_sent() ) {
  echo 'oh oh, something wnet wrong';
}
else {
  header('Content-type: text/xml; charset=utf-8');
  echo $doc->saveXML();
}
```